# Playing a sequence of audio clips in the background after a delay

Tags: ios, audio, avfoundation, avaudioplayer, avplayer

I would like to schedule a series of local audio tracks to play in sequence while my app is backgrounded or the device is locked, and after a delay. Furthermore, each track should only play a fixed duration sample. For example:

- User presses a button in my app.
- User locks device.
- After x minutes, tracks A, B, and C each play for y seconds in sequence.

How might I accomplish this?

My current Best Hope is to schedule these in an `AVPlayerQueue` since if I set up the queue correctly the background audio should then 'just work'. But I don't see any way to set a duration for each `AVPlayerItem`. I also don't know how to set an initial delay, though I would consider using looping a silent audio clip if that is the only obstacle.

Comment: What I would do (and I can see you are already thinking in these terms) is queue tracks that actually do what you want: e.g. x minutes of silence, y seconds of track A, y seconds of track B, y seconds of track C. You are going to need to be playing before you are backgrounded, even if what you are playing is silence, or else you won't be able to run in the background at all.

Comment: Thanks - are you suggesting I make trimmed copies of each of my source files at the time they are required? That seems reasonable, though I will have to check if it's possible for the tracks the user has selected from her music library.

Answer (score 0):

If you use [AudioKit](https://github.com/audiokit/AudioKit/tree/develop), something like will be easy to accomplish. Have a look at AKClipPlayer or AKPlayer. Both classes support scheduling and start/end time.